# While using number format in input ng-modal, angularjs throws error

Tags: angularjs

While using number format in input ng-modal, angularjs throws error

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idxyz" ng-model="valuex | number:2">
```

It does works but there is error in console

Comment: Use `ng-value` instead of `ng-model`: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idxyz" ng-value="valuex | number:2">`

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use filter 'number' when you are using two way data binding on input, instead you can do it on the controller using filter or use ng-value which behaves as read only.

**`DEMO`**

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',[])
app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.valuex = 5000;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app = "testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="idxyz" ng-value="valuex | number:2">
</body>
```